# Having problems with writing new lines to files including a variable

Tags: python

I'm finding it hard to write new lines every time to a text document using python.

When I write to a file it just replaces the first line with what was just written.

I have tried using `f.write(WhatPhone + '\n')` but it doesn't seem to work, what have I done wrong? I've tried loads of things.

```
                    WhatPhone = input('What Model would you like to be supported? Please Use the Format [brand] / [model] - ')
                AddSupportedModels.append(WhatPhone)
                with open('AddSuggestedPhone.txt','w') as out:
                    WhatPhone = WhatPhone
                    out.write('{}\n'.format(WhatPhone))
```

**Note:** I have also tried something else which can be found in the code above:

This is my entire program:

```
import time
import os
import sys


ContactManufacturer = "As there are no other solutions, we suggest you now contact your phones manufacturer."

AddSupportedModels = []

print('#################################################')
print('Welcome to our Automated Troubleshooting Service!')
print('#################################################')
print('')
print("Hello and welcome to our Automated Troubleshooting program!\n")
print("When Answering questions please...")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("1. Answer using YES and NO answers. Answers are not case sensitive")
print("2. Answer all questions fully and truthfully. The program may give false answers if you do not follow instructions.\n\n")

def AreYouReady():
    global AreYouReady
    AreYouReady = input('Are you ready for the support? - ')
    
def CorrectModel():
    global CorrectModel
    CorrectModel = input('You have selected '+WhatModel+' as your model, is this correct? - ').lower()

def WhatBrand():
    global WhatBrand
    WhatBrand = input('What Brand of Phone do you have? - ').lower()

def WhatModel():
    global WhatModel
    WhatModel = input('What Model do you have? - ').lower()
    
def DidThisWork():
    global DidThisWork
    DidThisWork = input('\n\nDid this solution work? - ').lower()

def SuggestModel():
    global SuggestModel
    SuggestModel = input('Would you like to suggest a model of your device to be added to the supported model list? - ').lower()

start = input("Please enter '1' to continue to the support. Please enter '2' to view suggestions for supported phones.")
if start == '2':
    simplejson.load(f)
    

#What Phone?
if start == '1':
    WhatPhone = input('Do you have Android or an iPhone? - ').lower()

        
#Android

    if WhatPhone == 'android':
        WhatBrand()
        if WhatBrand == 'samsung':
            WhatModel()
            if 's5' in WhatModel or 's5 edge' in WhatModel or 's6' in WhatModel or 's6 edge' in WhatModel or 's7' in WhatModel or 's7 edge' in WhatModel:
                CorrectModel()
            elif "note 7" in WhatModel:
                print("Return this device to Samsung right away as it is extremely faulty and may cause a lot of damange!")
            else:
                print("Selected Model not supported!")
                SuggestModel()
                if 'yes' in SuggestModel:
                    WhatPhone = input('What Model would you like to be supported? Please Use the Format [brand] / [model] - ')
                    AddSupportedModels.append(WhatPhone)
                    with open('AddSuggestedPhone.txt','w') as out:
                        WhatPhone = WhatPhone
                        out.write('{}\n'.format(WhatPhone))
            if CorrectModel == 'yes':
                AreYouReady()
        if WhatBrand == 'lg':
            WhatModel()
            if 'g6' in WhatModel or 'g5' in WhatModel or 'k10' in WhatModel or 'k4' in WhatModel:
                CorrectModel()
            else:
                print("Selected Model not Supported!")
            if CorrectModel == 'yes':
                AreYouReady()
        if WhatBrand == 'google':
            WhatModel()
            if 'pixel' in WhatModel or 'pixelxl' in WhatModel:
                CorrectModel()
            else:
                print("Selected Model not supported!")
            if CorrectModel == 'yes':
                AreYouReady()
        if WhatBrand == 'hauwei':
            WhatModel()
            if 'p10' in WhatModel or 'p10 plus' in WhatModel or 'mate 9' in WhatModel or 'p8 lite' in WhatModel or 'nova' in WhatModel or 'p9 plus' in WhatModel or 'p9 lite' in WhatModel:
                CorrectModel()
            else:
                print('Selected Model not supported!')
            if CorrectModel == 'yes':
                AreYouReady()
        if WhatBrand == 'nexus':
            WhatModel()
            if '5' in WhatModel or '6' in WhatModel or '5x' in WhatModel or '6p' in WhatModel:
                 CorrectModel()
            else:
                print('Selected Model not supported!')
            if CorrectModel == 'yes':
                AreYouReady()


    if AreYouReady == 'yes':
        yourproblem = input('What is your problem? - ')
        if 'screen' in yourproblem and 'not' in yourproblem:
            f = open("Solutions.txt","r")
            sol = f.readlines()
            print(sol[0])
            print("\n",sol[1])
            time.sleep(5)
            DidThisWork()
            if DidThisWork == 'no':
                print(sol[2])
            elif DidThisWork == 'yes':
                exit()
        if 'battery' in yourproblem and 'hot' or 'overheating' in yourproblem:
            print('Please power off your device for 10 minutes to let it cool down.')
            time.sleep(5)
            DidThisWork()
            if DidThisWork == 'no':
                print('Please use MalwareBytes to run a virus scan on your device. Viruses can overheat your battery.')
                time.sleep(5)
                DidThisWork()
                if DidThisWork == 'no':
                    print('Please factory reset your phone as this may be some sort of software causing the problem. Remember to backup important data so you dont lose it.')
                    time.sleep(5)
                    DidThisWork()
                    if DidThisWork == 'no':
                        print(ContactManufacturer)
        if 'phone' in yourproblem and 'slow' in yourproblem:
            print('Firstly, please reboot your device and see if this solves the problem.')
            time.sleep(5)
            DidThisWork()
            if DidThisWork == 'no':
                print("Please try uninstalling unnecessary applications from your phone.")
                time.sleep(5)
                DidThisWork()
                if DidThisWork == 'no':
                    print('Please use MalwareBytes to run a virus scan on your phone as viruses can slow down your phone.')
                    time.sleep(5)
                    DidThisWork()
                    if DidThisWork == 'no':
                        print(ContactManufacturer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> open() returns a file object, and is most commonly used with two
>   arguments: `open(filename, mode)`. [...] The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second argument is another string containing a few characters describing the way in which the file will be used. *mode* can be `'r'` when the file will only be read, `'w'` for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and `'a'` opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end. `'r+'` opens the file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; `'r'` will be assumed if it’s omitted.